# Getting outerWidth of element where text is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element.

```
var e=$('<span/>', {"class":'someClass',text:'Hello'});
```

I wish to get its outer width.  It appears that I cannot just use `e.outerWidth()` as it needs to be written to the screen first.  Correct?

So, now the real question.  Instead of using text "Hello", I wish to know the outer width if the text had been "Goodby"  How would this be accomplished?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the element to the document but outside the viewport, eg `left: -10000px`. Then `outerWidth()` would work.

Try this:

```
var e = $('<span/>', {"class":'someClass',text:'Hello'}).css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '-10000px'
}).appendTo('body');
var outerWidth = e.outerWidth();
e.remove(); // remove the element from the DOM once we've got it's width
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8egp/)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there's no real alternative as the element must be part of the DOM for a width to be calculated.

Comment: The problem with this approach is if there was any style on e's future parent which cascades.  Think it is best to put the other text in the same position, get the width, and then put the final text?  Or maybe copy the style to the outside viewport element (how is this done?)?